# use taxonomy to refine search results

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, taxonomy

I'm a newbie to web developement, and I'm having a little problem with my WordPress Template!
here's the page I'm talking about: [Click to see page](http://tritton.es/index.php/casas-rurales-en-sevilla/)

In this page you can only see accomodations in a certain location (in this case Sevilla), and what I want to do is to add extra filters to the sidebar in a form of a checkbox, so the user could select the type of accomodation they want with certain facilities. For exemple if the user checks swiming pool in the sidebar and clicks submit, they'll get the result with only accomodations with a swiming pool.

the sidebar comes in default with the Template and I know where to get to it, but I don't know how to add those extra filters.
I was thinking about using taxonomy as filters, since we check the facilities the accomodation has from a list when we create a new one! is it posible to do such thing?

I hope I was clear enough and excuse my english
i would appreciate if anyone could give me any guidance or how to do it! thank you

```
<?php
/**
 * The sidebar containing the main widget area.
 *
 * If no active widgets in sidebar, let's hide it completely.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage BookYourTravel
 * @since Book Your Travel 1.0
 */
?>
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <aside id="secondary" class="widget-area  lower" role="complementary">
        <ul>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </aside><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's the code that appears in sidebar.php

Maybe that's the sidebar code you wanted:

```
<!--sidebar-->
    <aside class="left-sidebar">
        <article class="refine-search-results">
            <form id="side-search" method="get" action="<?php echo $custom_search_results_page; ?>">
                <h2><?php _e('Refine search results', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></h2>
                <dl>
                    <input name="what" id="what" value="<?php echo $what;?>" type="hidden" />
                    <!--Price (per night)-->
                    <?php 

                        $price_range_bottom = of_get_option('price_range_bottom', '0');
                        $price_range_increment = of_get_option('price_range_increment', '50');
                        $price_range_count = of_get_option('price_range_count', '5');
                        $default_currency = strtoupper(of_get_option('default_currency_select', 'USD'));

                        if ($price_range_count > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($what == 1 || $what == 2) { ?>
                    <dt><?php _e('Price (per night)', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></dt>
                    <?php } elseif ($what == 3) { ?>
                    <dt><?php _e('Price (per day)', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></dt>
                    <?php } elseif ($what == 4) { ?>
                    <dt><?php _e('Price (per person)', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></dt>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <dd>
                        <?php 
                            $bottom = 0;
                            $top = 0;
                            $out = '';
                            for ($i=0; $i<$price_range_count;$i++) { 
                        ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="price<?php echo $i+1; ?>" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $i+1; ?>" />
                            <label for="price<?php echo $i+1; ?>">
                            <?php                               
                                $bottom = ($i * $price_range_increment) + $price_range_bottom;
                                $top = (($i+1) * $price_range_increment) + $price_range_bottom - 1;                             
                                $out = $bottom;
                                if ($i == ($price_range_count-1)) {
                                    $out.=  ' <span class="curr">' . $currency_symbol . '</span> +';
                                } else {
                                    $out.= " - " . $top . ' <span class="curr">' . $currency_symbol . '</span>';
                                }

                                echo $out;
                            ?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </dd>
                    <!--//Price (per night)-->
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ($what == 1 || $what == 2) { ?>
                    <dt><?php _e('Accommodation type', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($accommodation_types); $i++) { 
                        $accommodation_type = $accommodation_types[$i];
                    ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input value="<?php echo $accommodation_type->term_id; ?>" type="checkbox" id="ch<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" name="acc[]" />
                            <label for="ch<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"><?php echo $accommodation_type->name; ?></label>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </dd>
                    <!--//Accommodation type-->

                                                    <!--User rating-->
                    <dt><?php _e('User rating', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <div id="slider"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="rating" name="rating" value="" />
                        <span class="min">0</span><span class="max">10</span>
                    </dd>
                    <!--//User rating-->
                    <?php } elseif ($what == 3) { ?>
                    <dt><?php _e('Car type', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($car_types); $i++) { 
                        $car_type = $car_types[$i];
                    ?>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input value="<?php echo $car_type->term_id; ?>" type="checkbox" id="cth<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" name="car_types[]" />
                            <label for="cth<?php echo $i + 1; ?>"><?php echo $car_type->name; ?></label>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </dd>
                    <!--//Accommodation type-->
                    <?php } ?>
                </dl>

                <div class="f-item datepicker">
                    <span><?php _e('Date from', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>
                    <div class="datepicker-wrap"><input type="text" placeholder="" id="from" name="from" /></div>
                </div>
                <?php if ($what == 1 || $what == 2 || $what == 3) { ?>
                <div class="f-item datepicker">
                    <span><?php _e('Date to', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>
                    <div class="datepicker-wrap"><input type="text" placeholder="" id="to" name="to" /></div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($what == 1 || $what == 2) { ?>
                <div id="destination" name="destination" class="f-item">
                    <span><?php _e('Your destination', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('City, region, district or specific accommodation', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>" id="term" name="term" />
                </div>
                <?php } elseif ($what == 3) { ?>
                <div id="destination" name="destination" class="f-item">
                    <span><?php _e('Pick Up', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('I want to pick up car in', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>" id="term" name="term" />
                </div>              
                <div id="destination2" name="destination2" class="f-item">
                    <span><?php _e('Drop Off', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('I want to drop off car at', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>" id="term_to" name="term_to" />
                </div>              
                <?php } elseif ($what == 4) { ?>
                <div id="destination" name="destination" class="f-item">
                    <span><?php _e('Tour location', 'bookyourtravel'); ?></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('City, region, district or specific tour', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>" id="term" name="term" />
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Search again', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>" class="gradient-button" id="search-submit" />
            </form>
        </article>
    </aside>
    <!--//sidebar-->
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see when I look at the page under accommodations is hotel and villa. Those two seem to work fine. From what I see I cannot quite determine what your problem is. Could you reword it a little bit please?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll rephrase it!i want to add a new filter section called facilities just between accomodation type and user rating. The new filters, in a form of a checkbox, would be swimming pool, wifi, etc...

Comment: see this exemple http://www.amsterdamcityapartments.com/1-bedroom-apartment.html at the sidebar, under filter your results there's the aminities option, and I want to add something like that to my page!

Comment: Alright, the most helpful thing you could do is add the code for the theme's sidebar. Did you make the theme or did you download it?

Comment: I downloaded it! do you want me to add it here?

Comment: Ahh, okay. Do you have direct access to the code of have a link where I can download the theme from.

Comment: it's a payant theme, but I do have access to the entire Template, and php files in the server.

Comment: When you get a chance look for a file called sidebar. Usually the sidebar code would be in there. If I can get the code for the sidebar I can show you how to add the code you need. We'll get you there.

Comment: I couldn't answer with a comment, so i updated the OP

Comment: Alright so it is referencing an external file, I would suggest looking in the folder for the theme.

Comment: the last code I added is the one showing in the page I refered you to in the OP! Sorry I can't put in a better way due to newbies restrictions -_-'

Comment: Alright, that looks like what I was looking for. I will play around with it, have you tried taxonomy?

Comment: I would also recommend reading some of these tutorials / guides http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar http://wordpress.org/support/topic/editing-the-sidebar-2 http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/editing-sidebar https://managewp.com/edit-customize-wordpress-admin-sidebar-menu

Comment: Nop! I'm not sure I understand what you mean! I understand taxonomy as tags, and there's where I got stuck since I don't know how to use them! and Thanks for you're time I really appriciate it!